# Facebook scrapes my page completely wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook doesn't scrape my page correctly; it ignores all of my "og:" tags. and it says that I have META tags inside the BODY, which I don't.

So I clicked the link "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", and I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><htmldir lang="he" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
[...]
```

while the actual source code for my webspage (as see by Chrome's view-source feature) is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html
    dir="rtl" 
    lang="he"
    prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"
    >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
[...]
```

does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: please add your url, so we can test it

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: Can you try and write that `<html>` tag on one line? Also try to be consistent with spacing, you have a tabulator there before the dir attribute, but spaces before the next ones. Of course that is not a problem in HTML, but it looks like the scraper gets tripped up by this somehow.

Comment: Interesting observation @CBroe - I'll test this right now.

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE. @CBroe - you're a genius. This was indeed the problem. Faith in humanity restored; Faith in Facebook - well, I'll stop here. Thank you so much!